# android- How to Support Multiple screens

Tags: android

I implemented the application which supports different normal screens. For this, i created the 3 folders(like layout-normal-ldpi,layout-normal-mdpi,layout-normal-hdpi) in the res folder. In this i placed the different xml files with same name.But i got android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException. How to handle this? can anybody help me.

thanks.

Comment: Can you post a sample code or the exact logcat entries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The folder your created are incorrect refer to below ones

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

Below is pic for res folder structure for more simplicity

[image]

Comment: It means naming convention for normal screens--->layout-ldpi,layout-mdpi,layout-hdpi. small screens--->layout-small-ldpi,layout-small-mdpi,layout-small-hdpi. large screens --->layout-large-ldpi,layout-large-mdpi.layout-large-hdpi.is it correct?

Comment: There is nothing like layout-small-ldpi, but for layout its layout-small, etc and for drawables its drawable-mdpi, etc as described above

Comment: My screen size is 240x400(it means normal screen ldpi). For this it doesn't take the xml file from the layout folder why?

Answer (score 0):

I think the 'normal' and 'dpi' are redundant.
I guess you already looked [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) but maybe should review it again.